# Does repeatable read isolation level lock all table for update?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, transactions

Given two transactions:

**T1**

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

begin transaction
select * from tmp where val=1;
update tmp set txt='rerwer11' where val=1;

waitfor delay '00:00:7';

commit;
```

**T2**

```
set transaction isolation level repeatable read;

begin transaction

select * from tmp where val=2;
update tmp set txt='rerwer11' where val=2;

commit;
```

Start **T1** and while it is executing launch **T2**. I thought that first transaction locks only rows with `val=1` and thus second transaction does not have to be blocked because processes other rows. But it turned out that second transaction waits for first getting completed.
If i use default isolation level (read committed) for both of them and run `update` with `xlock` hint, everything works like I expected: sencond one get blocked only if it tries to read rows with `val=1`

Answer (score 0):

First of all Isolation levels never affect DDL,DML statements.They are only for select ..Secondly an update will never block the whole table unless accounting for some factors like no index(so table scan),lock escalation..

You are getting blocking in your example due to Repeatable read isolation level which keeps the select shared lock intact until the transaction is committed

Coming to your example
1.Select will never block the table ,but conflicting locks on the table are not allowed until the transaction is finished
2.if your update acquires more than 5000 locks,then it will block the whole table (not even select )

Comment: I resort to repeatable read exctly to prevent other transaction from modifying some rows. But WHY it locks all table? Does not it have to lock only rows that was been read?

Comment: repeatable read locks only the rows that are being read ,only serializable acquires range locks until end of transaction

Comment: to see why your table is blocked,see sys.dm_tran_locks

Comment: see if your update has crossed more than 5000 locks,then it will lock the table

Comment: i have no system rights. That's why my question was asked.

Comment: my table really small. It can not be a problem

Comment: ok. Does in my example second transaction have to be blocked?
If i understand right, according to your explantion T2 can not be blocked?

Comment: since T2 and T1 uses same tables,T2 might experience blocking for a little period of time

Comment: But previously you wrote: repeatable read locks only the rows that are being read. So T2 does not experience blocking, do it?

Comment: Lets discuss in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118436/discussion-between-thegameiswar-and-dotnetter).